# HTTP Call are not getting called only OPTIONS request are going Angular 4

Tags: java, node.js, angular

I am stucked at wired situation and scratching my head but not able to find the solution. I am doing some login using http using angular

```
onst basicAuthHeader = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders();

      headers.append('Authorization', basicAuthHeader);
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    this.http
      .post('/app/rest/v1/login', this.body, { headers: headers })
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log('Authentication succeed');
          this.setLoggedInState(basicAuthHeader);
          this.navigateToHomePage();
        },
        (err: any) => {
          this.handleError(err);
        });
```

As, you can see i have given the url pattern not the base URL like (http://localhost:port). Because, it is handled by my proxy :

```
{
  "/app/rest/v1/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8085",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

> I am trying to run this app on windows based server using express.

But, every time when i am trying to hit this URL i am only getting 404 NOT found because it is taking http://localhost:4200 but, it should take http://localhost:8085
[image]

Also, i am trying to hardcode the base url i.e: http://localhost:8085 i am getting the below error:

[image]

Backend side i have implemented the COROS filter but still i am getting this error.

Can anyone help me . Thanks.

Comment: When ever there is a preflight request (cross origin request) it is sent as OPTION request and after server approval it sends original request.  Please follow this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS          You need to send 200 ok response to option http request method .

Comment: @VikashKumar sorry but i know this concept by cors filter is not getting called at all.

Answer (score 0):

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and other CORS headers should be present on backend, not frontend. Note that.

Also, try:

```
{
  "/app/rest/v1/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8085",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Szczesniak i have done that but, just as a trial i was trying this.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting **Resource** specific headers in your Angular application, which is wrong. You have to set CORS allowance on your **Server**, not on your Client. 
Also pay attention when setting headers. It is recommended to also set the **allowed headers** and the **allowed methods**

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : "*"
Access-Control-Allow-Headers : "Content-Type"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods : "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"
```